# Apply VBA macro to multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, rows, col

I am relatively new to VBA and coding in general, so please bear with me if my language is inaccurate.

I'm trying to create a **bi-directional** unit converter, one that works both ways much like the one you can find on google. (example: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS902US902&sxsrf=ALeKk01haz9HbWVojCtcIMszToBVE-cDfg%3A1597171511150&ei=N-cyX97eCLivytMP17usiA8&q=google+unit+converter&oq=google+converter&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHUABYAGDSFmgAcAJ4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab)

I was able to create one that converts inches to feet, and vice versa, with the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Range("B7,D7"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If IsNumeric(Target) Then
        Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
            Case "B7": Range("D7").Value = [Convert(B7, "in", "ft")]
            Case "B8": Range("D8").Value = [Convert(B8, "in", "ft")]
        End Select
    Else
        Range("B7,D7").ClearContents
   End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
 
End Sub
```

So if I input "12" into cell B7 for inches, it changes cell D7 to "1" for feet. Likewise typing "2" feet into D7 results in "24" inches in B7

I would like to apply this macro to multipe rows (three in my case to do the same thing for length, width, and height); with enough fiddling I came up with the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Range("B7:B9,D7:D9"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If IsNumeric(Target) Then
        Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
            Case "B7": Range("D7").Value = [Convert(B7, "in", "ft")]
            Case "B8": Range("D8").Value = [Convert(B8, "in", "ft")]
            Case "B9": Range("D9").Value = [Convert(B9, "in", "ft")]
            Case "D7": Range("B7").Value = [Convert(D7, "ft", "in")]
            Case "D8": Range("B8").Value = [Convert(D8, "ft", "in")]
            Case "D9": Range("B9").Value = [Convert(D9, "ft", "in")]
        End Select
    Else
        Range("B7:B9,D7:D9").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

However, I'm sure there is a more efficient way of applying this formula. If I wanted 100 different rows of parameters to apply this to, I'd have to manually edit the "case" sections of the script twice as many times. How would I be able to generalize that editing issue? I would greatly appreciate any insight to this matter!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The target includes a row number, so you can update the matching row in the other column. You can use a basic If statement to check which column if being updated. In addition, you can use the WorksheetFunction object to get access to the built-in worksheet functions.

Here is the updated code. It will check for changes in rows 7 - 999.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Range("B7:B999,D7:D999"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If IsNumeric(Target) Then
        If Target.Column = Range("B1").Column Then
            Cells(Target.Row, Range("D1").Column) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Convert(Target, "in", "ft")
        Else
            Cells(Target.Row, Range("B1").Column) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Convert(Target, "ft", "in")
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```